# Number of elements in the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}_6 [x]/\langle 2x +4\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I am confused about this quotient ring.

I know that $\mathbb{Z}_7 [x]/\langle x^2 + 1\rangle =  \{ f(x) + \langle x^2 + 1\rangle \mid f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_7[x] \}$. Here $x^2 + 1$ is a zero element in $\mathbb{Z}_7 [x]/\langle x^2 + 1\rangle$, so if we replace $x$ by $i$ we get $\mathbb{Z}_7 [x]/\langle x^2 + 1\rangle =\mathbb{Z}_7 (i) $.

I know the distinct element of $ \mathbb{Z}_6 [x]/\langle 2x +4\rangle$ are $\langle 2x +4\rangle,\;x + \langle 2x +4\rangle, \;x^2 + \langle 2x +4\rangle, \ldots$ but I do not  know how to prove this.

Please tell what could we do similar here in case of $ \mathbb{Z}_6 [x]/\langle 2x +4\rangle$? Since $1$ is the zero element of the polynomial $2x +4 $. Why we can not replace here $x$ by $1$?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: We can't replace $x$ by $1$ since $4$ also is a zero point. So if we were to do any replacing, we would have to replace $x$ with both $1$ and $4$ at the same time. We can't do that, but we still know that $2x = 2$, regardless, so that is the substitution we can do.

Comment: think about the elements $x,x^2 , x^3 , x^4 , \ldots $ are any two of these equal in the quotient ring?

Comment: I will think about  both of your points

Comment: @Arthur: Your argument is not entirely convincing: $\Bbb Z [\Bbb i] \simeq \Bbb Z [X] / (X^2 + 1)$, so we "replace" $X$ by $\Bbb i$ despite the fact that $X^2 + 1$ has two roots, too.

Comment: @AlexM. Which is why I put it in a _comment_, not an answer. Your example is a quadratic equation, which you would _expect_ to have two solutions, while this one is a linear equation which _still_ has two solutions.

Comment: @Arthur: Agreed. And this is why I haven't considered your argument false, but merely unconvincing. Anyway, what drives me mad in this problem (as opposed to all the similar others on this site) is that $2$ is not invertible modulo $6$, therefore I cannot use the usual argument based upon Euclidean division. If a polynomial has coefficients $0, 2, 4$ than it can be divided (with remainder) by $2x + 4$, therefore one only has to study polynomials of the form $a_0 + a_1 x + \dots + a_n x^n$ with $a_i =0$ or $1$, but how?

Comment: @baharampuri: Are there?

Comment: @Alex M. 2(x+4) does not divide $x^m-x^n$ as integer polynomials and a simple argument will show that it does not divide modulo 6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In principle, problems of this type ar given either over fields, or at least for ideals generated by polynomials with invertible leading coefficient, and they are generally solved by using Euclid's algorithm for polynomial division. Alas, the fact that $2$ is not invertible in $\Bbb Z _6$ makes this approach infeasible.

Note though that if a polynomial $f$ has all the coefficients $0$, $2$ or $4$, then you would write it as $2g$ and you could perform the Euclidean division not of $f$ by $2x + 4$, but rather of $g$ by $x + 2$. This is the idea that we shall follow. Split any polynomial $f \in \Bbb Z _6 [x]$ into a part $f _\text{even}$ with even coefficients and a rest $f_2$with coefficients either $0$ or $1$ (this splitting is unique). Next, there exist $q \in \Bbb Z _6 [x]$ and $r_f \in \Bbb Z _6$ such that $f _\text{even} = (2x+4) q + r_f$. Note that $r_f = f _\text{even} (1) \in \{0,2,4\} \subset \Bbb Z _6$. Since this set is a subring isomorphic to $\Bbb Z _3$, identify $r_f$ with $\widehat {r_f} \in \Bbb Z _3$, its class modulo $3$.

Consider now the morphism $\Bbb Z _6 [x] \to \Bbb Z _2 [x] \times \Bbb Z _3$, given by $f \mapsto (f_2, \widehat {f _\text{even} (1)})$. Its kernel is made of all those polynomials that have no "odd" part and when divided by $2x+4$ produce no remainder, therefore are multiples of $2x+4$. Thus, the kernel is exactly the ideal $(2x+4)$ and by the fundamental isomorphism theorem this gives $$\frac {\Bbb Z _6 [x]} {(2x+4)} \simeq \Bbb Z _2 [x] \times \Bbb Z _3 .$$

In particular, this ring has infinitely many elements.

Comment: Thanks to all of them who give me your valuable time.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an isomorphism using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).
\begin{align*}
\frac{(\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z})[x]}{(2x+4)} &\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(6, 2x+4)} = \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(2)(3, x+2)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(2)} \times \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(3, x+2)}\\
&\cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[x] \times \frac{(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})[x]}{(x+2)}  \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[x] \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}
The first isomorphism is the [Third Isomorphism Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Third_isomorphism_theorem) and the second equality follows since the ideals $(6, 2x+4) = (2)(3, x+2)$ are equal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.  Since $1 = -2 + 3 \in (2) + (3, x+2)$, then $(2)$ and $(3, x+2)$ are [comaximal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers#Coprimality_in_ring_ideals), so we can apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem.  Finally, the isomorphism $\frac{(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})[x]}{(x+2)} \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is induced by the evaluation map at $-2$.

Comment: So this ring has infinitely many elements and the question in the title is misleading. I was suspecting something along similar lines but was colliding with the title.

Comment: More explicitly, the isomorphism is given the following way: given an element $f\in\Bbb Z_6[x]/(2x+4)$, there is a unique representative $\bar f\in \Bbb Z_6[x]$ of $f$ where all coefficients except perhaps the constant term are $0$ or $1$. That, together with whether the constant term of $\bar f$ is even or odd gives you an element in $\Bbb Z_2[x]$. The element of $\Bbb Z_3$ is given by the constant term of $\bar f$ modulo $3$.

Comment: @Arthur: This is what I was thinking when I wrote the comment under the OP's original question.

Comment: @Arthur I'm not sure about your description of the map in the second factor.  To get the entry in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ in the isomorphism I've written down, one evaluates the polynomial at $-2 = 1$ (which amounts to adding the coefficients), then reduces mod $3$.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @SpamIAm I suspect you are right. I wrote my comment without thinking much.

Comment: @Arthur: I've written an answer, is this what you had in mind?