# Properties of the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}_6[x]/\langle2x+4\rangle$

Tags: ring-theory

Consider the ring  $R = \mathbb{Z}_6[x]/\langle2x+4\rangle$ . Which of the following are true?

1. $R$ has infinitely many elements.
2. $R$ is a field.
3. $5$ is a unit in $R$.
4. $4$ is a unit in $R$.

I know that $R = \mathbb{Z}_6[x]/\langle2x+4\rangle = \{f(x)+\langle2x+4\rangle\mid f(x)\in{\mathbb{Z}_6[x]}\}$ and that $(2x+4) + \langle2x+4\rangle = 0+ \langle2x+4\rangle$, which implies $x=-2$ in $R$.

also $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is not field and $(2x+4) = 2(x+2)$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}_6[x]$ (also $2x+4$ has a zero in $\mathbb{Z}_6$).

I know that if I will prove that R is not ID then it is not field but I am not getting any direction

Please give me some direction.

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` for angle brackets, not `<` and `>`. The latter are relation symbols; they look different, and give you wrong spacing. (I fixed it for you.)

Comment: As another note, not to be too negative, but you should try to be consistent, standard, and concise with your notation. For example, once you've used $\mathbb{Z}$ to denote the integers, you shouldn't switch to $Z$. You also switch from $(2x+4)$ to $\langle 2x+4 \rangle$ after the first line. Since $R$ is a ring, you should put it in math mode. You should also avoid writing sets as $\{x / y\}$ and rather use $\{x : y\}$ or $\{x \mid y\}$.

Comment: How exactly does $2x+4 \equiv 0$ imply $x\equiv -2$, when $2$ is a zero-divisor?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of research would have saved some time here! Parts of this question have been answered elsewhere.

1. Yes, it has infinitely many elements, as described here: [Number of elements in the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}_6 [x]/\langle 2x +4\rangle$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1321589/number-of-elements-in-the-quotient-ring-mathbbz-6-x-langle-2x-4-rangle?rq=1)
2. As you already figured out, it is not a field, as $2x+4$ is a reducible polynomial.
3. $5$ is a unit, as it is coprime to $6$
4. $4$ is not a unit, as it is not coprime to $6$, and is therefore a zero-divisor.